# Dynamics CRM 2013: setLabel() doesn´t work on navigation items

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I have the problem that I can´t set the label of navigation links via:

```
function RenameNavItem(id, newName) {
    try{
        var elem = Xrm.Page.ui.navigation.items.get(id);
        elem.setLabel(newName);
      }
    catch (err) {
        console.error("RenameNavItem " + id + ": " + err.message);
    }
}
```

while I can get the label text via getLabel() the setLabel() function doesn´t change the caption. It also doesn´t produce an error.

Does anyone know if that´s a bug .. or maybe a feature ^^?

Answer (score 1):

Using your same code, I renamed one of the common nav items to "Test" and it worked fine.

[image: Renamed the 3rd one to "Test"]

Comment: That´s funny.. I wonder what the difference could be. Do you use an on-premise system? Do you have UR 1 installed?

Comment: Are you passing a number of a guid?  If guid, try this line and see what happens. Xrm.Page.ui.navigation.items.get(0).setLabel('Test Label');

Comment: I tested in an online environment and a UR2 - both by index though

Comment: No, I was passing the id of the navigation item. Which should have worked, because I can get a reference to  the element as I see in the debugger. Now I tried to set the label by index, but this doesn´t work, too.  :(

Comment: If you are testing from the IE or chrome console, use: frames[0].Xrm.Page.ui.navigation.items.get(0).setLabel('Test Label');